# How to recover from interrupted CPAN module installation?

Tags: perl, installation, perl-module, cpan

My computer crashed during a perl module installation using `cpanm` (I guess while installing `Carp` as a dependency of `Moose`). Now, when I try to use the modules I want to use, I get the following error:

```
user@linux:~$ ./script_using_moose.pl 
Carp.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.14/diagnostics.pm line 185.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.14/diagnostics.pm line 185.
Compilation failed in require at ./script_using_moose.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./script_using_moose.pl line 5.
user@linux:~$
```

And if I try to (re)install the package (using `cpanm --reinstall` or `cpanm force`) I get this other (similar) error:

```
user@linux:~$ sudo cpanm --force Moose
Carp.pm did not return a true value at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Parse/CPAN/Meta.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Parse/CPAN/Meta.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /loader/0x1692090/App/cpanminus/script.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /loader/0x1692090/App/cpanminus/script.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpanm line 2029.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpanm line 2029.
user@linux:~$
```

How can I resume installation or reconfigure/reinstall the incomplete module?

Comment: `Carp` is a really important Core module and not generally considered to be a prerequisite worth mentioning. Have you tried `cpanm Carp` and its variations? In case that doesn't work either: could you show us the contents of `Carp.pm`?

Comment: `cpanm Carp` gives me the same error as above (the same one from `cpanm --force Moose`). According to `find` there are 5 files named `Carp.pm` in my computer:  one providing `CGI::Carp`, another providing `Carp` (at `/usr/share/perl/5.14.2/Carp.pm`) ... and the other three are blank. Two of these are in folders under `~/.cpanm/work` and the other is in `/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Carp.pm`. Those blank files do not look good...

Comment: You can delete the `~/.cpanm` folder to reset the cpanm state, but having a blank file in a proper module location is weird. In what order are the module locations checked (`perl -E'say for @INC'` does the trick)?

Comment: I deleted the `~/.cpanm` folder, but the error remains unchanged. I copied the file from `/usr/share/perl/5.14.2/Carp.pm` on top of the blank file and tried installing again, and even though it did start to run, the installation failed some tests and did not go through. Here's the `build.log`: https://gist.github.com/jjatria/46c53fca4827ff5a1df3. This is the output you asked for:
`/etc/perl; 
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2; 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2; 
/usr/lib/perl5; 
/usr/share/perl5; 
/usr/lib/perl/5.14; 
/usr/share/perl/5.14; 
/usr/local/lib/site_perl; 
.`

Comment: Some modules appear to have a version number of `undef`. Those have to be reinstalled, I'm afraid. Here: `Task::Weaken`, and `Devel::GlobalDestruction`

Comment: That did it! Installing those two got me through it. If you want to put this as an answer I can accept it. Otherwise, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, a couple of files were created but not written to, or truncated. These can be easily identified in the full installation log as those modules with an `undef` version number:

```
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
...
Checking if you have Task::Weaken 0 ... Yes (undef)
...
Checking if you have Devel::GlobalDestruction 0 ... Yes (undef)
```

Reinstalling the modules `Task::Weaken`, and `Devel::GlobalDestruction` should do the trick.